# DB2+IBM MQ; enable_MQFunctions = Error -- while connecting to database

Tags: shell, docker, db2, dockerfile, ibm-mq

I build docker's image containing IBM MQ 9.1, DB2express-c 9.7 + ubuntu 16.04 64bit.
I want to enable MQ functions(sending msg to queue) on my Db2 database.
But when I used *enable_MQFunctions* than I got this error:

```
 *** Error -- while connecting to TEST  
      Make sure that user(db2inst1) and password(pass) are valid and that the DB2 instance has started.  
 *** enable_MQFunction finished with error
```

Database, user, pass are all okey. And i Don't understand than before this command w/o problems connected to my database

Dockerfile I today used(with only DB2 and IBM MQ, w/o IIB):

```
# © Copyright IBM Corporation 2015, 2017
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

#==============================





#========================
#FROM centos:7
FROM ubuntu:16.04
#FROM ubuntu:17.10


#LABEL maintainer "Arthur Barr <arthur.barr@uk.ibm.com>, Rob Parker <PARROBE@uk.ibm.com>"

#LABEL "ProductID"="98102d16795c4263ad9ca075190a2d4d" \
#      "ProductName"="IBM MQ Advanced for Developers" \
 #     "ProductVersion"="9.0.4"

# The URL to download the MQ installer from in tar.gz format
#oryginal ARG MQ_URL=https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/messaging/mqadv/mqadv_dev904_ubuntu_x86-64.tar.gz
ARG MQ_URL=http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/messaging/mqadv/mqadv_dev910_ubuntu_x86-64.tar.gz
#ARG MQ_URL=http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/messaging/mqadv/mqadv_dev80_linux_x86-64.tar.gz
#ARG MQ_URL=\\172.29.5.249\mqadv_dev910_ubuntu_x86-64.tar.gz

# The MQ packages to install
ARG MQ_PACKAGES="ibmmq-server ibmmq-java ibmmq-jre ibmmq-gskit ibmmq-web ibmmq-msg-.*"

#RUN rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get clean -y 
RUN apt-get autoclean -y 

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
  # Install additional packages required by MQ, this install process and the runtime scripts  
  && apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  # && yum update -y \
 #  && yum install -y \
    bash \
    bc \
    ca-certificates \
    coreutils \
    curl \
    debianutils \
    file \
    findutils \
    gawk \
    grep \
    libc-bin \
    lsb-release \
    mount \
    passwd \
    procps \
    sed \
    tar \
    util-linux \
  # Download and extract the MQ installation files
  && export DIR_EXTRACT=/tmp/mq \
  && mkdir -p ${DIR_EXTRACT} \
  && cd ${DIR_EXTRACT} \
  && curl -LO $MQ_URL \
  && tar -zxvf ./*.tar.gz \
  # Recommended: Remove packages only needed by this script
#
  #&& package-cleanup --leaves --all \ <-------moje dodanie
  # Recommended: Create the mqm user ID with a fixed UID and group, so that the file permissions work between different images
  && groupadd --system --gid 990 mqm \
  && useradd --system --uid 990 --gid mqm mqm \
  && usermod -G mqm root \
  # Find directory containing .deb files
  && export DIR_DEB=$(find ${DIR_EXTRACT} -name "*.deb" -printf "%h\n" | sort -u | head -1) \
  # Find location of mqlicense.sh
  && export MQLICENSE=$(find ${DIR_EXTRACT} -name "mqlicense.sh") \
  # Accept the MQ license
  && ${MQLICENSE} -text_only -accept \
  && echo "deb [trusted=yes] file:${DIR_DEB} ./" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/IBM_MQ.list \
  # Install MQ using the DEB packages
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y $MQ_PACKAGES \
  # Remove 32-bit libraries from 64-bit container
  && find /opt/mqm /var/mqm -type f -exec file {} \; \
    | awk -F: '/ELF 32-bit/{print $1}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm -f \
  # Remove tar.gz files unpacked by RPM postinst scripts
  && find /opt/mqm -name '*.tar.gz' -delete \
  # Recommended: Set the default MQ installation (makes the MQ commands available on the PATH)
  && /opt/mqm/bin/setmqinst -p /opt/mqm -i \
  # Clean up all the downloaded files
  && rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/IBM_MQ.list \
  && rm -rf ${DIR_EXTRACT} \
  # Apply any bug fixes not included in base Ubuntu or MQ image.
  # Don't upgrade everything based on Docker best practices https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#run
  && apt-get upgrade -y sensible-utils \
  # End of bug fixes
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  # Optional: Update the command prompt with the MQ version
  && echo "mq:$(dspmqver -b -f 2)" > /etc/debian_chroot \
  && rm -rf /var/mqm \
  # Optional: Set these values for the Bluemix Vulnerability Report
  && sed -i 's/PASS_MAX_DAYS\t99999/PASS_MAX_DAYS\t90/' /etc/login.defs \
  && sed -i 's/PASS_MIN_DAYS\t0/PASS_MIN_DAYS\t1/' /etc/login.defs \
  && sed -i 's/password\t\[success=1 default=ignore\]\tpam_unix\.so obscure sha512/password\t[success=1 default=ignore]\tpam_unix.so obscure sha512 minlen=8/' /etc/pam.d/common-password

#==========db2 expres START====
#FROM centos:7

#MAINTAINER Leo Wu <leow@ca.ibm.com>

###############################################################
#
#               System preparation for DB2
#
###############################################################
#********************z iib-mq-db2 git
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
 && apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl \
    bash \
    bc \
    coreutils \
    curl \
    debianutils \
    findutils \
    gawk \
    grep \
    libc-bin \
    lsb-release \
    libncurses-dev \
    libstdc++6 \
    gcc \
    binutils \
    make \
    libpam0g:i386 \
    lib32stdc++6 \
    lib32gcc1 \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev:i386 \
    numactl \
    libaio1 \
    libxml2 \
    mount \
    passwd \
    procps \
    rpm \
    sed \
    tar \
    wget \
    util-linux 

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get dist-upgrade -y
#******************

RUN groupadd db2iadm1 && useradd -G db2iadm1 db2inst1

# Required packages

#RUN yum install -y \
#    vi \
#    sudo \
#    passwd \
#    pam \
#    pam.i686 \
#    ncurses-libs.i686 \
#    file \
#    libaio \
#    libstdc++-devel.i686 \
#    numactl-libs \
#    which \
#    && yum clean all

ENV DB2EXPRESSC_DATADIR /home/db2inst1/data

# IMPORTANT Note:
#  Due to compliance for IBM product, you have to host a downloaded DB2 Express-C Zip file yourself
#  Here are suggested steps:
#    1) Please download zip file of db2 express-c from http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express-c/download.html
#    2) Then upload it to a cloud storage like AWS S3 or IBM SoftLayer Object Storage
#    3) Acquire a URL and SHA-256 hash of file and pass it via Docker's build time argument facility

ARG DB2EXPRESSC_URL=ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express/db2exc_images/db2exc_970_LNX_x86_64.tar.gz

#ARG DB2EXPRESSC_URL=http://lorenzana.gt/uploads/files/v10.5fp1_linuxx64_expc.tar.gz
#ARG DB2EXPRESSC_URL=\\172.29.5.249\public\image\v10.5fp1_linuxx64_expc.tar.gz


ADD db2expc.rsp /tmp/db2expc.rsp
ADD db2rfe.cfg /home/db2inst1/sqllib/instance/db2rfe.cfg

COPY db2expc.rsp /tmp
RUN curl -fkSLo /tmp/expc.tar.gz $DB2EXPRESSC_URL
RUN cd /tmp && tar xf expc.tar.gz

RUN rm -rf /home/db2inst1/sqllib
RUN mkdir /home/db2inst1/sqllib
RUN su - root -c "chmod -R 1777 /home/db2inst1/"

 RUN su - db2inst1 -c "/tmp/expc/db2_install -f sysreq -b /home/db2inst1/sqllib"
# RUN su - db2inst1 -c "/tmp/expc/db2setup -r /tmp/db2expc.rsp" || echo "db2setup failed"

 RUN echo '. /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile' >> /home/db2inst1/.bash_profile \
    && rm -rf /tmp/db2* && rm -rf /tmp/expc* \
    && sed -ri  's/(ENABLE_OS_AUTHENTICATION=).*/\1YES/g' /home/db2inst1/sqllib/instance/db2rfe.cfg \
    && sed -ri  's/(RESERVE_REMOTE_CONNECTION=).*/\1YES/g' /home/db2inst1/sqllib/instance/db2rfe.cfg \
    && sed -ri 's/^\*(SVCENAME=db2c_db2inst1)/\1/g' /home/db2inst1/sqllib/instance/db2rfe.cfg \
    && sed -ri 's/^\*(SVCEPORT)=48000/\1=50000/g' /home/db2inst1/sqllib/instance/db2rfe.cfg \
    && mkdir $DB2EXPRESSC_DATADIR && chown db2inst1.db2iadm1 $DB2EXPRESSC_DATADIR

RUN su - db2inst1 -c "db2start && db2set DB2COMM=TCPIP && db2 UPDATE DBM CFG USING DFTDBPATH $DB2EXPRESSC_DATADIR IMMEDIATE && db2 create database db2inst1" \
    && su - db2inst1 -c "db2stop force" \
    && cd /home/db2inst1/sqllib/instance \
&& ./db2rfe -f ./db2rfe.cfg


#COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
#ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

#VOLUME $DB2EXPRESSC_DATADIR

#EXPOSE 50000

#=========db2 express END ====


COPY *.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY *.mqsc /etc/mqm/
COPY admin.json /etc/mqm/

COPY mq-dev-config /etc/mqm/mq-dev-config

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/*.sh

# Always use port 1414 (the Docker administrator can re-map ports at runtime)
# Expose port 9443 for the web console
#VOLUME /home/db2inst1/data

EXPOSE 1414 9443 50000

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
#ENTRYPOINT ["mq.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh (with MQ and DB2 commands):

```
#======= start MQ =====
set -e
mq-license-check.sh
echo "----------------------------------------"
source mq-parameter-check.sh
echo "----------------------------------------"
setup-var-mqm.sh
echo "----------------------------------------"
which strmqweb && source setup-mqm-web.sh
echo "----------------------------------------"
mq-pre-create-setup.sh
echo "----------------------------------------"
source mq-create-qmgr.sh
echo "----------------------------------------"
source mq-start-qmgr.sh
echo "----------------------------------------"
source mq-dev-config.sh
echo "----------------------------------------"
source mq-configure-qmgr.sh
echo "----------------------------------------"
exec mq-monitor-qmgr.sh ${MQ_QMGR_NAME}
#======== z MQ - END ====== 
pid=0

function log_info {
 echo -e $(date '+%Y-%m-%d %T')"\e[1;32m $@\e[0m"
}
function log_error {
 echo -e >&2 $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T")"\e[1;31m $@\e[0m"
}

function stop_db2 {
  log_info "stopping database engine"
  su - db2inst1 -c "db2stop force"
}

function start_db2 {
  log_info "starting database engine"
  su - db2inst1 -c "db2start"
}

function restart_db2 {
  # if you just need to restart db2 and not to kill this container
  # use docker kill -s USR1 <container name>
  kill ${spid}
  log_info "Asked for instance restart doing it..."
  stop_db2
  start_db2
  log_info "database instance restarted on request"
}

function terminate_db2 {
  kill ${spid}
  stop_db2
  if [ $pid -ne 0 ]; then
    kill -SIGTERM "$pid"
    wait "$pid"
  fi
  log_info "database engine stopped"
  exit 0 # finally exit main handler script
}

trap "terminate_db2"  SIGTERM
trap "restart_db2"   SIGUSR1

if [ ! -f ~/db2inst1_pw_set ]; then
  if [ -z "$DB2INST1_PASSWORD" ]; then
    log_error "error: DB2INST1_PASSWORD not set"
    log_error "Did you forget to add -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=... ?"
    exit 1
  else
    log_info "Setting db2inst1 user password..."
    (echo "$DB2INST1_PASSWORD"; echo "$DB2INST1_PASSWORD") | passwd db2inst1 > /dev/null  2>&1
    if [ $? != 0 ];then
      log_error "Changing password for db2inst1 failed"
      exit 1
    fi
    touch ~/db2inst1_pw_set
  fi
fi
if [ ! -f ~/db2_license_accepted ];then
  if [ -z "$LICENSE" ];then
     log_error "error: LICENSE not set"
     log_error "Did you forget to add '-e LICENSE=accept' ?"
     exit 1
  fi

  if [ "${LICENSE}" != "accept" ];then
     log_error "error: LICENSE not set to 'accept'"
     log_error "Please set '-e LICENSE=accept' to accept License before use the DB2 software contained in this image."
     exit 1
  fi
  touch ~/db2_license_accepted
fi

if [[ $1 = "-d" ]]; then
  log_info "Initializing container"
  start_db2
  log_info "Database db2diag log following"
  tail -f ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump/db2diag.log &
  export pid=${!}
  while true
  do
    sleep 10000 &
    export spid=${!}
    wait $spid
  done
else
  exec "$1"
fi
```

and than:

```
docker run -e LICENSE=accept  -e MQ_QMGR_NAME=MQ321 -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=pass -p 41419:1414 -p 9459:9443 -p 5015:50000 allall4r
```

And after all, I used command from : [HERE](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/implementing-mq-functions-in-db2-luw/) 
So I executed:
**root:**

```
  usermod -G mqm db2inst1
  /opt/mqm/bin/setmqinst -i -n Installation1 -p /opt/mqm
```

**mqm user:**

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/mqm/bin
```

**db2inst1 user**:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/mqm/lib64
AMT_DATA_PATH=/opt/mqm

db2start
db2 create db testdb
db2 connect to testdb

cd ~/sqllib/cfg/mq
db2 –tvf amtsetup.sql
```

Upload with all files needed to build this image are here: [UPLOAD LINK](https://ufile.io/js0ey7rf)
Image will be about 3.1GB

Comment: Edit your question to show *how*  (exact command line) and *where*  and *when * you run the enable_MQFunctions command.  That is important because it has documented pre-reqs (See the usage notes here https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/blob/9.1.2/Dockerfile-server

Comment: After I built image, ran it, I use exacly this commands -> https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/implementing-mq-functions-in-db2-luw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the cause of your symptom is that the account specified for `enable_MQFunctions` command line does not have a password *at the time* that `enable_MQFunctions` tries to run.  You can prove this by looking at `db2diag.log` to see the exact authentication failure message, and/or by looking at the `/etc/passwd` entry for that account just before you run `enable_MQFunctions`.

You can expand the `Dockerfile` to configure the Db2 for MQ entirely during the `docker build` instead of running those steps after `docker run` or in entrypoints. That way you are responsible for all the steps inside the Dockerfile and it will be repeatable without manual intervention after the `docker run` command. It also means that your built image is pre-baked with all of the required configuration which will then be persistent. You need to have enough competence with scripting in the Dockerfile to get the desired outcome.

When correctly done, the enable_MQFunctions will operate properly during `docker  build`, so if you are getting errors it's because you are doing it incorrectly.

I can successfully configure the database and run `enable_MQFunctions` all inside the Dockerfile, with these steps below (because of using a non-root install of Db2), so all the configuration is already in the built image.

- after installing Db2 and before db2start the Dockerfile should
  create `/home/db2inst1/sqllib/userprofile` (which will run whenever the instance-owner accounts dots in its `db2profile` from `.bash_profile` or `.profile`), to do these steps:

  -- append `/opt/mqm/lib64` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

  -- `export AMT_DATA_PATH=/opt/mqm`

  -- prepend `/opt/mqm/bin` on the `PATH`
- `chown db2inst1:db2iadm1 /home/db2inst1/sqllib/userprofile`
- after installing Db2 and before `db2start`, the Dockerfile should run these steps:

  -- `db2set DB2COMM=TCPIP`

  -- `db2set DB2ENVLIST=AMT_DATA_PATH`

  -- `db2 -v update dbm cfg using federated yes immediate`
- set a password for db2inst1 account in the Dockerfile
- the Dockerfile can then run `db2start`, create the database ( i call it sample, you can call it whatever you like)  and run the fragment below as user db2inst1 to first create the required objects in the database used by the MQ functions:

`su -db2inst1 -c "( db2 -v connect to sample ; \
     db2 -tvf /home/db2inst1/sqllib/cfg/mq/amtsetup.sql; \
     db2 -v list tables for schema DB2MQ ; \
     exit 0 ) "`

Notice that you have to run `amtsetup.sql` in a subshell ,as shown, to explicitly exit 0, because `amtsetup.sql` always returns non-zero exit code even when it completes successfully. So you want the `docker build` to continue in that case.

If all the above steps completed successfully and MQ is already successfully installed, later in the `Dockerfile` you can run the `enable_MQFunctions` as follows:

*I use ARG INSTANCE_PASSWORD to specify the db2inst1 password, which can come from external.*

`su - db2inst1 -c "( . ./.profile ;\
                             db2start ;\
                             db2 -v activate database sample ;\
                             cd /home/db2inst1/sqllib/cfg ; \
                             /home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/enable_MQFunctions -echo -force -n sample -u db2inst1 -p $INSTANCE_PASSWORD ; \
                             db2stop force ; \
                             exit 0)"`

Comment: Indeed, after I looked at *db2diag.log* it shows no validation for password after *enable_MQFunctions*. Now I am preparing new dockerfile. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with environment variables. My image, after built, can't hold any variable. I try with export prefix but no change. So no password, no good LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Event after I change and logout, variable back to default.
After I used `root -> passwd` on my account (*db2inst1*) I can execute enable_MQFunction with good password
Next error is that I dont have valid license for db2..